# Fetch the rows with unique value in a particular column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, unique

I have the following mysql query -:

I have a  table ->

```
feed_id | by_id | sharer
```

It has following values ->

```
 (1 , 1 , NULL)  , (2, 1, iop_23) , (3, 1, iop_23)
```

I run this query
`SELECT * FROM feed WHERE by_id = 1 GROUP BY sharer ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 10`

With this query I am trying to fetch the rows which have either sharer = NULL or if not NULL then a Unique Value.

It should return -> `(1 , 1 , NULL) , (3, 1, iop_23)`

But it is returning -> `(1 , 1 , NULL)  , (2, 1, iop_23)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is returning the wrong value is because you have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by` and that have no aggregation functions.  The results are indeterminate.

If you want the one with the biggest id:

```
select s.*
from sharer s left outer join
     (select sharer, max(feed_id) as maxf
      from feed
      group by sharer
     ) sf
     on s.feed_id = maxf
where s.sharer is null or sf.sharer is not null
```

You need the left outer join to get all the NULL values.  The `where` clause is to select between the NULL values on the one hand and the max id rows on the other.

It looks like you want the row with the biggest `id` for each `sharer` plus all the rows with NULL values.  Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but that is my interpretation.

This finds those rows by first finding the maximum id for each sharer, and then joining this back to the original data.

Comment: Please can you explain a bit @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct result for a `GROUP BY`.  To get the last record returned for the group, you'd need an inner query to sort first, then group in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM feed WHERE by_id = 1 ORDER BY feed_id DESC
) AS `a` GROUP BY sharer LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT max(feed_id) as feed_id ,by_id ,sharer FROM feed 
   WHERE by_id = 1 
   GROUP BY sharer 
   ORDER BY feed_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07856/2)